# How to set a windows form as the main form of the application? C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using Visual Studio C# and I got stuck in making a new form become the main one. I need the application to be closed when it get closed and I want to close the previous form without closing the application.

Current attempt (won't work):

```
FormClass newForm = new FormClass();
newForm.Show()

previousForm.Close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First understand why the Application is exiting. From the [documentation of Application.Run(Form)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902.aspx):

> This method adds an event handler to
>   the mainForm parameter for the Closed
>   event. The event handler calls
>   ExitThread to clean up the
>   application.

**If you can get away with just hiding it rather than closing it**

```
FormClass newForm = new FormClass();
newForm.Show();

previousForm.Hide();
```

**If you need to close it (or would rather)**

Alter Program.cs. To prevent the event handler added by Run(Form) from terminating you, use an overload of Run() that doesn't add such a handler:

```
var form = new Form1();
form.Show();
Application.Run(); // The application will not exit when form is closed
```

But in this case, you will need to call Application.Exit() yourself when the newForm is closed (or under any other circumstances in which you want to Exit).

Comment: Nice -- I never realized that Application.Run(Form) actually registered an event handler.

Comment: It's one of those things we don't look at too often, right? :)

Answer (score -1):

If your intent is to use something like a splashscreen, try call the first form on a background thread, them abort the thread after the task if completed. The "first" form will be closed.

Or, just close the "splashscreen form", ending the background thread.

It helps?

Comment: This is a horrible idea.  You should hardly ever abort threads, and all user interface code should be on a single thread.

Comment: Well, i don't think this is a horrible idea. Several splashscreen samples use this technique. And, by the question, i really don't know if this will be a good way to do what druttka intents. I'm just given ideas how to accomplish the task.